# dplyr: custom function in summarize_at

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'd like to use my own function `smd` in `summarize_at`, without success. If I try to do:

```
library(dplyr)

# My function
smd<-function(x,...)
  {sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)-1)}

starwars %>%
  summarise_at(c("height", "mass"), smd, na.rm = TRUE)

Erro: C stack usage  15924224 is too close to the limit
```

Doesn't work!! Try to make `funs(smd)`and `funs(sd/sqrt(n()-1))` and dosen't work too!

Please, any ideas?

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine, except that it returns only NAs

Comment: You can include the `...` in the `sd` function and that will fix the error, but that also changes the length so you need to account for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change is to pass `na.rm=` on to `sd(.)`, so

```r
smd <- function(x, ...) sd(x, ...)/sqrt(length(x)-1)
starwars %>%
  summarise_at(c("height", "mass"), smd, na.rm=TRUE)
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#   height  mass
#    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1   3.75  18.3
```

As @astrofunkswag suggested, though, you need to consider if `NA` values should decrease your length. For that, we need to replace `length(x)` with `sum(!is.na(x))`.

```r
smd <- function(x, ...) sd(x, ...)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(x))-1)
starwars %>%
  summarise_at(c("height", "mass"), smd, na.rm=TRUE)
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#   height  mass
#    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1   3.89  22.3
```

Comment: Why @r2evans if I use `group_by` in `starwars%>% group_by(gender) %>% summarise_at(c("height", "mass"), smd, na.rm=TRUE)` doesn't work?                                                Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `height`.
x unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)
i Input `height` is `(function (x, ...) ...`.
i The error occurred in group 1: gender = "feminine".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this with `summarise/across`

```
smd <- function(x, ...) sd(x, ...)/sqrt(sum(complete.cases(x))-1)
starwars %>%
     summarise(across(c(height, mass), smd, na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  height  mass
#   <dbl> <dbl>
#1   3.89  22.3
```